# how to use a log scale for y-axis of histogram in R?

Tags: r, statistics, histogram

I have a large dataset with the lifespan of threads on an discussion board. I want  a histogram that shows the distribution of lifespan, so I did this:

```
dall <- read.csv("lifespan.csv")
colnames(dall) <- c("thread.id", "seconds.alive", "start.time")
hist(dall$seconds.alive)
```

which generated this hard to read image:
[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/285483/tmp/screenshot297.png]

My questions are
a) is changing y-axis to a log-scale a good way to make it more readable? Apparently [some people think is a bad idea](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/Rhelp10/2010-August/250909.html) to change y-axis to log.

b) how do I do that?

Comment: Given the that bars start at zero, and log(0) is -infinity, what exactly would you want the graph to display?

Comment: Something similar was discussed @ CrossValidated: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1764/what-are-alternatives-to-broken-axes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try using `hist(log10(dall$seconds.alive))` instead.

Also try specifying `breaks=100` or smaller/larger number:

```
hist(log10(dall$seconds.alive), breaks=100)
```

Comment: +1 good point, log-seconds are definitely better than log-counts

Comment: doesn't that effectively apply a log scale to the **x** (instead of the y) axis ?