# I need ggplot scale_x_log10() to give me both negative and positive numbers as output

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, histogram

I generate a fine histogram here with both positive and negative numbers.

```
x <- rnorm(5000,0,1000)
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x)) + geom_histogram()
```

[image]

What I want is to have a logged x-axis. When I do this for only positive numbers with scale_x_log10(), it works like a charm. But here it does not and it either removes my negative numbers are adds them to the positive numbers.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x)) + geom_histogram() + scale_x_log10()
```

[image]

All I really want is for the ticks and the spacing between the ticks to follow the log pattern and for either side of 0 on the x-axis to be mirror images of each other but I cannot seem to get that.

Comment: You can't take the logarithm of a negative number, which is why ggplot is cutting off your axis.

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504869/histogram-with-negative-logarithmic-scale-in-r

Comment: Perhaps a signed square root would be a more appropriate transformation?

Comment: @MhairiMcNeill Sadly I already read that and it did not. Thanks anyway

Comment: @MichaelGao, I get that, but I feel there should be an equivalent thing to get a plot to look the way I want. I have seen such plots but I do not know how to get them.

Comment: well, where have you seen such plots?  Can you provide a link/description of what they did?

Answer (score 16):

This is possible to do by defining a new transformation (a "signed log", `sign(x)*log(abs(x))`; the [asinh transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_function#asinh) suggested by [Histogram with "negative" logarithmic scale in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504869/histogram-with-negative-logarithmic-scale-in-r) might be more principled, or a signed square root as suggested in the comments above), but I question whether it's a good idea or not. Nevertheless ... ("Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime; give him a rope, and he can go hang himself ...") ... you can define your own axis transformations via `trans_new` as shown below.

Setup:

```
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
set.seed(101)
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(5000,0,1000))
```

Set up the new transformation:

```
weird <- scales::trans_new("signed_log",
       transform=function(x) sign(x)*log(abs(x)),
       inverse=function(x) sign(x)*exp(abs(x)))
```

Try it out -- first on the raw points:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x,x))+geom_point()+
    scale_y_continuous(trans=weird)
```

[image]

Now on the histogram:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x)) + geom_histogram()+
    scale_x_continuous(trans=weird)
```

[image]

Things you should worry about:

- this transformation is going to be nonsensical when you have values between -1 and 1
- you might have to worry about transforming the axis of a histogram without scaling bin height appropriately: it may give you a misleading impression of the probability density -- although in this case `ggplot(df, aes(x = weird$transform(x))) + geom_histogram()` looks about the same as the plot above ...

Comment: Thank you. When I try to apply this to some code that I am calling a column in a complex dataframe, the $ is giving an error in the `weird <- scales::trans_new("signed_log",
       transform=function(x) sign(x)*log(abs(x)),
       inverse=function(x) sign(x)*exp(abs(x)))` part of the code

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not enough information for me to troubleshoot your problem.  If you just want to do the transformation outside ggplot (which would be simpler), define `signedlog <- function(x) sign(x)*log(abs(x))`

Comment: I would also consider using `log1p` and `expm1` in the transform.

Answer (score 0):

This works with small numbers!

```
if (require("lme4") && require("glmmTMB")) { 
weird <- scales::trans_new("signed_log",
       transform=function(x) sign(x)*log1p(abs(x)),
       inverse=function(x) sign(x)*expm1(abs(x)))

p<- plot_model(fit.me.model)

p+ scale_y_continuous(trans=weird)
}
```

[image]

[r](/questions/tagged/r) [randomeffects](/questions/tagged/randomeffects) [lme4](/questions/tagged/lme4) [glmmtmb](/questions/tagged/glmmtmb)